# Return all records regardless if there is a match

Tags: t-sql, join

In my Table 1, It may have AND have a null entry in the address column to corresponding record OR not have a matching entry in Table 2.
I want to present all the records in Table 1 but also present corresponding entries from Table 2.   My RESULT is what I am trying to achieve.

```
Table 1         
ID  First   Last    
1   John    Smith   
2   Bob     Long    
3   Bill    Davis   
4   Sam     Bird    
5   Tom     Fenton  
6   Mary    Willis  

Table 2         
RefID   ID  Address 
1       1   123 Main    
2       2   555 Center  
3       3   626 Smith   
4       4   412 Walnut  
5       1       
6       2   555 Center  
7       3       
8       4   412 Walnut  

Result          
Id  First   Last    Address
1   John    Smith   123 Main
2   Bob     Long    555 Center
3   Bill    Davis   626 Smith
4   Sam     Bird    412 Walnut
5   Tom     Fenton  
6   Mary    Willis
```

Comment: How do you join your two tables? I assume from your example result that RefId in table2 is a foreign key to Id in Table1?  If that's the case then @Nicholai's answer will work.  What does the Id column in Table2 refer to?

Answer (score 1):

You need an outer join for this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.RefID
```

Comment: that didnt work for me.  If my Table 1 had 100 records, My result should only return 100 records.

Comment: Are the fields in my answer not the correct fields for the join? Please edit the question to show the query you have been using, and describe your table relationships.

Comment: You didnt include the Address portion from Table 2 where I was needing it to correspond to the relationship ID field from Table 1, if it existed.  I didn't have a query to use as a basis because my try at it was simply not working.  I apologize if my question was not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

How do you join those two tables? If table 2 have more than 1 matched address, how do you want display them?   Please clarify in your question.

Here is a query based on my assumptions.

```
SELECT
  ID, First, Last,
  Address =  (SELECT MAX(Address) FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID)
FROM Table1 t1
```

Comment: I just want to display the match address from Table 2 with an actual entry that isnt null, but also to include all the entries from Table 1 so if their isnt a match that record will display as a null in the address portion.  I just tested your code and it seems to work.